# WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, go

Why do I get this error when trying to connect to a websocket via `wss://` but seems to work fine with `ws://`?

## error

```
WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

## code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    //"encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var clients map[*websocket.Conn]*Client

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    CheckOrigin : func(r *http.Request) bool{
        return true
    },
}

type Client struct{
    session_id  string
    block_id    uint
    module      string
}

func main(){
    var port uint = 8000

    http.HandleFunc("/", handleConnections)

    log.Printf("Websocket server started on: %d", port)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}

func handleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    //  Upgrade initial GET request to a websocket
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)

        return
    }

    defer ws.Close()

    log.Print("Connection established to IP: ", r.RemoteAddr)

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is only listening for HTTP connections so you should use `ws` when making a connection. `wss` is "WebSocket Secure" which really just means a WebSocket connection that is served over HTTPS (TLS)

From the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-55)

```
A |wss| URI identifies a WebSocket server and resource name and
indicates that traffic over that connection is to be protected via
TLS (including standard benefits of TLS such as data confidentiality
and integrity and endpoint authentication).
```